# How to make a VBA commandbutton looks like was clicked?

Tags: excel, commandbutton, vba

I was looking over the Internet and could not find a solution to my problem.

I would like to make a VBA commandbutton look like it was clicked. 
To be precise I want it to look like it was pressed. It is easy to change background or foreground but is there a way to make it look like it is pressed?

Comment: hm... tried use `.SpecialEffect = fmButtonEffectSunken` but I get an error: Run-time error 387 Set not permitted. I read `Although the SpecialEffect property exists on the ToggleButton, the property is disabled.` from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868258%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Hm... focused on code rather than just try using it. It is excacly what I was looking for. Thanks Rory! You can post an anwser so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a ToggleButton instead, its default behaviour is exactly what you are looking for. :)